# React application shows blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Register from './Register';
import LandingPage from './LandingPage';
import OrderMedicine from './OrderMedicine';
import Supply from './Supply';
import Track from './Track';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
// import parseCSV from './drugsData';
// import DrugRecommendation from './DrugRecommendation';

function App() {
return (
\<div className="App"\>
\<Navbar bg={window.location.pathname === "/" ? "transparent" : "primary"} expand="lg" variant="dark"\>
\<Container\>
\<Navbar.Brand href="/"\>
<img height="36" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFNmtBoYNk7fg/company-logo_200_200/0/1582999540395?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=e32Kjj8eEAe6gpjMdtY80-O02ZQV9GsZqKnYjXflHJo" /> WEB 3.0
\</Navbar.Brand\>
\<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbar-nav" /\>
\<Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-nav"\>
\<Nav className="me-auto"\>
\<Nav.Link href="/register" className={window.location.pathname === "/register" ? "active-link" : ""}\>Register\</Nav.Link\>
\<Nav.Link href="/order-medicine" className={window.location.pathname === "/order-medicine" ? "active-link" : ""}\>Order Medicines\</Nav.Link\>
\<Nav.Link href="/control-supply-chain" className={window.location.pathname === "/control-supply-chain" ? "active-link" : ""}\>Control Supply Chain\</Nav.Link\>
\<Nav.Link href="/track-medicine" className={window.location.pathname === "/track-medicine" ? "active-link" : ""}\>Track Medicines\</Nav.Link\>
\<Nav.Link href="/drug-recommendation" className={window.location.pathname === "/drug-recommendation" ? "active-link" : ""}\>Drug Recommendation\</Nav.Link\>
\</Nav\>
\</Navbar.Collapse\>
\</Container\>
\</Navbar\>
\<Router\>
\<Routes\>
\<Route path="/" element={\<LandingPage/\>} /\>
\<Route path="/register" element={\<Register/\>} /\>
\<Route path="/order-medicine" element={\<OrderMedicine/\>} /\>
\<Route path="/control-supply-chain" element={\<Supply/\>} /\>
\<Route path="/track-medicine" element={\<Track/\>} /\>
{/\* \<Route path="/drug-recommendation" element={\<DrugRecommendation/\>} /\> \*/}
\</Routes\>
\</Router\>

    </div>

);
}

export default App;\
```

This application is loading. But when I un-comment this line in the Routes section

```
({/* <Route path="/drug-recommendation" element={<DrugRecommendation/>} /> */} )
```

the app goes blank. No errors are shown so hard to detect what is going wrong.

DrugRecommendation.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { parseCSV } from './drugsData';
import drugsData from './drugsData'; //Importing the drugs data array

const csvURL = 'file_path_in_my_device';

function DrugRecommendation() {
const \[condition, setCondition\] = useState('');
const \[recommendedDrugs, setRecommendedDrugs\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[error, setError\] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                //Fetch and parse the CSV data
                const parsedData = await parseCSV(csvURL);
    
                //Filter the drugs based on the selected condition
                const filteredDrugs = parsedData.filter(drug => drug.Condition.toLowerCase().includes(condition.toLowerCase()));
                setRecommendedDrugs(filteredDrugs);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching and parsing CSV:' , error);
            }
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, [condition]);
    
    const handleInputChange = event => {
        setCondition(event.target.value);
        setError('');
    };
    
    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        if (condition.trim() === '') {
            setError('Please enter a condition.');
            setRecommendedDrugs([]);
        } else {
            const filteredDrugs = recommendedDrugs.filter(drug => drug.Condition.toLowerCase().includes(condition.toLowerCase()));
    
            if (filteredDrugs.length === 0) {
                setError(`No drugs found for the condition "${condition}"`);
            }
    
            setRecommendedDrugs(filteredDrugs);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="drug-recommendation-page">
            <h1>Drug Recommendation</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="condition-input">Enter a condition:</label>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    id="condition-input"
                    value={condition}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    placeholder="Enter condition"
                />
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            {error && <p className="error-message">{error}</p>}
            {recommendedDrugs.length > 0 ? (
                <div className="recommended-drugs">
                    <h3>Recommended Drugs:</h3>
                    <ul>
                        {recommendedDrugs.map(drug => (
                            <li key={drug.DrugName}>
                                {drug.DrugName} (Score: {drug.MeanNormalizedScore})
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ) : (
                !error && <p>No drugs found for the entered condition.</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default DrugRecommendation;\
```

drugsData.js

```
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';

export const parseCSV = async (csvURL) =\> {
try {
const response = await fetch(csvURL);
const text = await response.text();
const parsedData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =\> {
parse(text, {
columns: true,
skip_empty_lines: true,
}, (err, records) =\> {
if (err) {
reject (err);
} else {
resolve(records);
}
});
});

    return parsedData;

} catch (error) {
throw new Error('Error fetching and parsing CSV : ' + error.message);
}
};

export default drugsData;\
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
// const EslintWebpackPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");

const extensions = \[".js", ".jsx"\];

module.exports = {
mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development",
entry: "./src/index.js",
output: {
path: path.resolve(\__dirname, "dist"),
filename: 'bundle.js',
publicPath: '/'
},
resolve: {
extensions,
fallback: {
stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
},
},
devServer: {
static: {
directory: path.resolve(\__dirname, "dist"),
},
hot: true,
historyApiFallback: true,
client: {
overlay: false,
},
},

module: {
rules: \[
{
test: /.js$/i,
use: \[
{
loader: "babel-loader",
options: {
presets: \["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env" \],
},
},
\],
exclude: /node_modules/,
},
{
test: /.css$/i,
use: \["style-loader", "css-loader"\],
},
{
test: /.s\[ac\]ss$/i,
use: \["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"\],
},
{
test: /.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
type: "asset/resource",
},
{
test: /.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
type: "asset/resource",
},
\],
},

plugins: \[
// //     new EslintWebpackPlugin({ extensions }),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
template: path.resolve(\__dirname, "./public/index.html"),
filename: 'index.html'
}),
\],
//   stats: "minimal",
};\
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
\<React.StrictMode\>
\<App /\>
{typeof window !== "undefined" && window.location.pathname !== "/" && \<footer className="footer"\>
\<div\>Developed By : Geetika Raut\</div\>
\</footer\>}
\</React.StrictMode\>
);
```

- drugsData.js -- is trying to convert data from a csv file and store it as an array. The csv file contains columns Condition, DrugName, MeanNormalizedScore`
- DrugRecommendation -- is trying to use the above array to take input a condition from the user and display the drugs associated with that condition.`

Help me to resolve this issue and load the application and the drug recommendation system to work correctly for this.

Comment: Where do you look for errors?

Comment: I'm assuming that you've also removed the ```//``` from 
```// import DrugRecommendation from './DrugRecommendation';```

when you uncommented 

```{/\* \<Route path="/drug-recommendation" element={<DrugRecommendation/\>} /\> \*/}```

Comment: Yesss. I followed all the steps of importing correctly but still the application goes blank